# How to close a webpage spawned by a link click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a webpage with a link which opens a new, totally different, webpage. In its simplest form the former looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div_id" class="page-content">
    <a id="myId" target="_blank" href="myPage.html">Open Page</a>
</div>

<script>
    // this doesnt work, it closes the wrong page
    function closePage(myBoolean){
        if (myBoolean){
            window.close()
        }
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I want to write a function to close the newly created webpage if a condition is met. What is shown in my code above doesnt work since it closes the main webpage not the spawned one.

How can I do this please?

Comment: You can't close windows you didn't open, but if you open the window via [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) it will return a reference to the opened window, which you can then call [window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) on. Note: Popup blockers may interfere with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle que `click` event from the `a` tag yourself. So you can call `window.open(url)` which returns the instance of the window just opened.

```
const link = document.querySelector(`#myId`);
let w;

link.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    // Opens the page and stores the opened window instance
    w = window.open(`./myPage.html`);
});

function closePage(myBoolean) {
    if (myBoolean && w) {
        w.close();

        // Preventing weird behaviors
        w = null;
    }
}
```

You need to delete the `href` attribute from your anchor tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, great many thanks. I will definitely accept  that as an answer but could you please correct a typo?  (not sure if you will be able to do it after acceptance..) Towards the end, `wndow` should be `w`. Do you know btw how I can have the hand cursor when I mouseover that link please?

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing that out! I forgot to change that part after editing, my bad. On the other hand, in your CSS declare your link (id or class, whatever) with the property `cursor: pointer;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myWindowOpen {
  myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", “myWindow", "width=250, height=250");
}

function myWindowClose { 
  if (myWindow) { 
    myWindow.close();
    myWindow = null;
  }
}
```

You need write link to a new window in a variable. And when a condition is met -> call `myWindowClose`